# regex re.compile evaluating \b as \\b in python

Tags: python, regex

I wrote:-

```
r = re.compile('|'.join([fr'\b[^-_]{email}\b' for email in self.member_email_domains()]), flags=re.I)
```

when i print r it gives `re.compile('\\b[^-_]grad.edu\\b|\\b[^-_]m.grad.edu\\b', re.IGNORECASE)`
i want \b not \\b

i even used \\b in the place of \b but it did not help
language used python

Comment: Python's doing exactly what it should. You're just reading it wrong.

Comment: `r'\b' == '\\b'` evaluates to `True`.  Two different syntaxes to generate a two-character string: a backslash and a `b`.

Answer (score -1):

Printing a compiled regex shows you, in Python syntax, how to create an equivalent regex object.  Note that the resulting expression does *not* use a raw string literal like your original input does, so it must escape the `\b` to match.  In other words, the two are equivalent.

If you instead use `print(r.pattern)`, that might clear up your confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you. Now i know what i was missing. but i still do not understand when i used this regex in regex101.com it matched my string grad.edu but in python code it keeps on going to else.findall returns an empty array

```
class Member:
    def member_email_domains(self):
      # ipdb.sset_trace()
      return ['grad.edu', 'm.grad.edu']
      # if self.email_domain:
      #           return self.email_domain
      # return [self.web_domain]

    def is_valid_email_for_member(self, email):
        email_domain = email.split('@')[-1]
        print(email_domain)
        r = re.compile('|'.join([fr'\b[^-_]{email}\b' for email in self.member_email_domains()]), flags=re.I)
        print(r.pattern)
        if re.search("^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*[[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", email_domain):
            if r.findall(email_domain):
                    print('true')
        return False

email='mahak.malik@grad.edu'
```